# My attempt at outcomes for rolling two dies - is there an error?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, probability, dice

The problem I seek to solve is returning the most likely outcomes for the sum of two die rolls. The input is the number of sides on each die space separated. The output is a list of the most likely outcomes, in ascending order. So for the input "6 6" we should expect 7. This is found by drawing a table of rows 6 and columns 6 and counting that the sum 7 appears more than any other sum. The code below works for all displayed test cases but is failing the grader (edge cases, larger inputs). Can you think of what the issue may be?

Per the website "if your program is rejected on a secret testcase you more than likely have a serious bug in your program".

```
package xyz;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class dicecup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        String[] parts = s.split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); // sides on die one
        int m = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); // sides on die two
        int min = n;
        if (m < n) {
            min = m;
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                sums.add(i + j);

            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sums.size(); i++) {
            strings.add(sums.get(i).toString());
        }
        int max = min;
        ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            if (Collections.frequency(strings, strings.get(i)) == max) {
                outputs.add(strings.get(i));
            }

        }

        HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>(outputs);
        for (String str : uniqueValues) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no checking for bad inputs. For example, try entering "0 0"

Comment: Another one is a lopsided pair: 1 56